# Regexvalidator's validaterequestmode=enabled not working properly in asp.net

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, xhtml

**Note: If you need, you can have a look at my project(issue I am getting is in Login-Signup.aspx   page.) Click [HERE](https://github.com/Omkaragrawal/Abhiyantrix) to get to project.**

I have added some regex validator control in my webform. I had set it's property validaterequestmode to enabled and checked it. It used to work perfectly,what I mean is if there is a space in my first name textbox then it at that instance showed the error (without changing focus) and likewise for others. I added some functions to my js and I didn't even possibly link them, and now when I run the page it doesn't validates the input until and unless I change the focus.Please help me to solve this.

---

****NOTE:** 
I do not have any problem with regex,etc it's just the validaterequestmode property I am concerned with.**

---

I am adding my html code below:
(It is for signup view)

```js
//Donot uncomment any line. dare not uncommenting any line untill permission granted.
// Donot use the access key  and the function verify() untill permission granted.
// set endpoint and your access key



var access_key = 'my_key';
var email_address;
var valid_format, smtp_check, disposable, mxfound, Urole;

function setmail() {
  email_address = document.getElementById('TextBox11').value;
  // document.getElementById('Label5').textContent = email_address;
  verify();
}

// verify email address via AJAX call
function verify() {
  $.ajax({
    url: 'http://apilayer.net/api/check?access_key=' + access_key + '&email=' + email_address,
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function validate(json) {

      //Access and use your preferred validation result objects
      console.log(json.format_valid);
      console.log(json.smtp_check);
      console.log(json.score);
      console.log("disposable:   " + json.disposable);
      console.log(json.role);
      console.log(json.mxfound);



      //valid_format = json.valid_format ;
      //smtp_check = json.smtp_check ;
      //disposable = json.disposable;
      //mxfound = json.mxfound ;
      //Urole = json.role;

      document.getElementById("HFformatvalid").innerHTML = json.valid_format;
      document.getElementById("HFsmtpcheck").innerHTML = json.smtp_check;
      document.getElementById("HFdisposable").innerHTML = json.disposable;
      document.getElementById("HFmxfound").innerHTML = json.mxfound;
      document.getElementById("HFrole").innerHTML = json.role;
      emailchck("HFformatvalid", "HFsmtpcheck", "HFdisposable", "HFmxfound", "HFrole");
    }
  });
}

function emailchck(id1, id2, id3, id4, id5) {
  valid_format = document.getElementById(id1).innerText;
  smtp_check = document.getElementById(id2).innerText;
  disposable = document.getElementById(id3).innerText;
  mxfound = document.getElementById(id4).innerText;
  Urole = document.getElementById(id5).innerText;
  if ((valid_format == "true" && smtp_check == "true" && disposable == "false" && mxfound == "true" && Urole == "false")) {
    //document.getElementById("HFemail").innerText = document.getElementById("TextBox11").innerText;
    document.getElementById("HFemail").innerText = email_address;
    document.getElementById("Label4").innerHtml = email_address + "<br />disposable= " + disposable + "<br />Smtp check= " + smtp_check + "<br /> mxfound= " + mxfound + "<br />Urole= " + Urole + "<br />valid format= " + valid_format;
  } else {
    // document.getElementById("Label17").innerText = "";
    if (valid_format == "false") {
      document.getElementById("Label17").innerHTML += "Invalid email format" + "<br />";
    }
    if (smtp_check == "false") {
      document.getElementById("Label17").innerHTML += "Invalid email" + "<br />";
    }
    if (disposable == "true") {
      document.getElementById("Label17").innerHTML += "Please Donot use diaposable email" + "<br />";
    }
    if (mxfound == "false") {
      document.getElementById("Label17").innerHTML += "Cannot send email to your mail. Please use a genuine email id" + "<br />";
    }
    if (Urole == "true") {
      document.getElementById("Label17").innerHTML += "Invalid email.Use proper email id" + "<br />";
    }
  }
}

function assign(idfrom, idto) {

  document.getElementById(idto).innerText = document.getElementById(idfrom).innerText;
}

function verify() {

}


//document.getElementById('SUSbmtBtn').onclick(function () {

//    email_address = document.getElementById('TextBox11').value;
//    document.getElementById('Label5').textContent = email_address;

//});
```

```html
<%@ Page Language="C#" UnobtrusiveValidationMode="none" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Login-Signup.aspx.cs" Inherits="Abhiyantrix.Login_Signup" %>

  <!DOCTYPE html>

  <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

  <head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <%--<link href="Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="Content/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />--%>
      <%--<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />--%>
        <link href="Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  </head>

  <body style="background-color: #DFE2DB">

    <form id="form1" runat="server">
      <asp:HiddenField ID="HFformatvalid" runat="server" />
      <asp:HiddenField ID="HFsmtpcheck" runat="server" />
      <asp:HiddenField ID="HFdisposable" runat="server" />
      <asp:HiddenField ID="HFmxfound" runat="server" />
      <asp:HiddenField ID="HFrole" runat="server" />
      <asp:HiddenField ID="HFaccept" runat="server" />
      <asp:HiddenField ID="HFfname" runat="server" />
      <asp:HiddenField ID="HFsname" runat="server" />
      <asp:HiddenField ID="HFemail" runat="server" />
      <asp:HiddenField ID="HFpass" runat="server" />
      <asp:HiddenField ID="HFphno" runat="server" />
      <asp:HiddenField ID="HFut" runat="server" />
      <div>

        <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server"></asp:Label>
        <br />
        <br />
        <asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server"></asp:Label>
        <br />
        <br />

        <asp:MultiView ID="MultiView1" runat="server">
          <asp:View ID="Login" runat="server" OnActivate="Page_Load">
            <div style="background-color: #FFF056">
              <asp:Label ID="Label8" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" Font-Italic="True" Font-Size="Larger" Text="Email"></asp:Label>
              &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
              <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox7" runat="server" ValidateRequestMode="Enabled" ValidationGroup="LoginIn" TextMode="Email" class="input input-sm form-control" placeholder="Enter your email here"></asp:TextBox>
              &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
              <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator7" runat="server" ControlToValidate="TextBox7" ErrorMessage="*Enter Your Email ID" ValidationGroup="LoginIn"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            </div>
            <br />
            <br />
            <div style="background-color: #FFF056">
              <asp:Label ID="Label9" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" Font-Italic="True" Font-Size="Larger" Text="Password"></asp:Label>
              &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;
              <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox8" runat="server" ValidateRequestMode="Enabled" ValidationGroup="LoginIn" TextMode="Password" class="input input-sm form-control" placeholder="Enter your password here"></asp:TextBox>
              &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
              <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator8" runat="server" ControlToValidate="TextBox8" ErrorMessage="*Enter your password" ValidationGroup="LoginIn"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            </div>
            <br />
            <br />
            <div style="background-color: #FFF056">
              <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Height="45px" Text="Login" Width="118px" ValidationGroup="LoginIn" OnClick="Button1_Click" class="btn btn-danger btn-lg" />
            </div>
            <br />
            <br />
            <br />
            <div style="background-color: #D9853B">
              <asp:Button ID="Button3" runat="server" Height="44px" OnClick="Button3_Click" Text="Signup" Width="105px" UseSubmitBehavior="False" ValidationGroup="ChangeView" ViewStateMode="Enabled" class="btn btn-warning btn-lg" />
            </div>
          </asp:View>
          <asp:View ID="Signup" runat="server">
            <div style="background-color: #A2AB58">
              <div style="background-color: #D9853B">
                <asp:Label ID="Label10" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" Font-Italic="True" Font-Size="Larger" Text="First Name"></asp:Label>
                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox9" runat="server" Font-Size="Larger" ValidateRequestMode="Enabled" ValidationGroup="SignUp" MaxLength="10" class="input input-sm form-control" Columns="4" placeholder="Enter your first name here" onblur="assign(this.id,HFfname)"
                  AutoCompleteType="FirstName" CausesValidation="True"></asp:TextBox>
                &nbsp;
              </div>
              <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="TextBox9" ErrorMessage="*Please enter your first name" ForeColor="Red" ValidationGroup="SignUp" SetFocusOnError="True" ValidateRequestMode="Enabled" Display="Dynamic"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
              <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator3" runat="server" ControlToValidate="TextBox9" ErrorMessage="Only alphabets allowed; upto 15 alphabets with no spaces." ForeColor="Red" SetFocusOnError="True" ValidateRequestMode="Enabled"
                ValidationExpression="^([a-z,A-Z]{1,10}$)" Display="Dynamic" EnableClientScript="False"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
              <br />
              <br />
              <div style="background-color: #D9853B">
                <asp:Label ID="Label11" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" Font-Italic="True" Font-Size="Larger" Text="Last Name"></asp:Label>
                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox10" runat="server" Font-Size="Larger" ValidateRequestMode="Enabled" ValidationGroup="SignUp" MaxLength="10" class="input input-sm form-control" placeholder="Enter your last name here" onblur="assign(this.id,HFsname)"></asp:TextBox>
              </div>
              <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" runat="server" ControlToValidate="TextBox10" ErrorMessage="*Please enter your last name" ForeColor="Red" ValidationGroup="SignUp" SetFocusOnError="True" ValidateRequestMode="Enabled" Display="Dynamic"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
              <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator4" runat="server" ControlToValidate="TextBox10" ErrorMessage="Only alphabets allowed; upto 15 alphabets with no spaces." ForeColor="Red" SetFocusOnError="True" ValidateRequestMode="Enabled"
                ValidationExpression="^([a-z,A-Z]{1,10}$)" ValidationGroup="SignUp" Display="Dynamic"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
              <br />
              <br />
              <div style="background-color: #D9853B">
                <asp:Label ID="Label12" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" Font-Italic="True" Font-Size="Larger" Text="Email"></asp:Label>
                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox11" runat="server" Font-Size="Larger" ValidationGroup="SignUp" OnTextChanged="TextBox11_TextChanged" class="input input-sm form-control" placeholder="Enter your email name here" name="TextBox11" onblur="setmail()" MaxLength="50"></asp:TextBox>
                &nbsp;
              </div>
              <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator3" runat="server" ControlToValidate="TextBox11" ErrorMessage="*Check your Email -ID" ForeColor="Red" ValidationGroup="SignUp" SetFocusOnError="True" ValidateRequestMode="Enabled" Display="Dynamic"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
              <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator2" runat="server" ControlToValidate="TextBox11" ErrorMessage="*Check youe Email - ID" ForeColor="Red" SetFocusOnError="True" ValidateRequestMode="Enabled" ValidationExpression="^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&amp;'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?)*$"
                ValidationGroup="SignUp" Display="Dynamic"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
              <asp:Label ID="Label17" runat="server"></asp:Label>
              <br />
              <br />
              <div style="background-color: #D9853B">
                <asp:Label ID="Label13" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" Font-Italic="True" Font-Size="Larger" Text="Password"></asp:Label>
                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox12" runat="server" class="input input-sm form-control" Font-Size="Larger" MaxLength="15" onblur="assign(this.id,HFpass)" placeholder="Enter your password here" TextMode="Password" ValidationGroup="SignUp"></asp:TextBox>
              </div>
              <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator4" runat="server" ControlToValidate="TextBox12" ErrorMessage="*Password required" ForeColor="Red" ValidationGroup="SignUp" SetFocusOnError="True" ValidateRequestMode="Enabled" Display="Dynamic"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
              <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator5" runat="server" ControlToValidate="TextBox12" ErrorMessage="Password length must be between 7 to 15 alphanumeric characters with @&amp;#" ForeColor="Red" ValidationExpression="^[a-zA-Z0-9'@&amp;#.\S]{7,15}$"
                ValidationGroup="SignUp" SetFocusOnError="True" ValidateRequestMode="Enabled" Display="Dynamic"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
              <br />
              <br />
              <div style="background-color: #D9853B">
                <asp:Label ID="Label14" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" Font-Italic="True" Font-Size="Larger" Text="Confirm Password"></asp:Label>
                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox13" runat="server" class="input input-sm form-control" Font-Size="Larger" placeholder="Confirm your password" TextMode="Password" ValidationGroup="SignUp" ValidateRequestMode="Enabled"></asp:TextBox>
                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
              </div>
              <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator5" runat="server" ControlToValidate="TextBox13" ErrorMessage="*Confirm Password required" ForeColor="Red" ValidationGroup="SignUp" SetFocusOnError="True" ValidateRequestMode="Enabled" Display="Dynamic"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
              <asp:CompareValidator ID="CompareValidator1" runat="server" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="2px" ControlToCompare="TextBox12" ControlToValidate="TextBox13" ErrorMessage="*Confirm password should match with password" ForeColor="Red" ValidationGroup="SignUp"
                SetFocusOnError="True" ValidateRequestMode="Enabled"></asp:CompareValidator>
              <br />
              <br />
              <div style="background-color: #D9853B">
                <asp:Label ID="Label15" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" Font-Italic="True" Font-Size="Larger" Text="Contact number"></asp:Label>
                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox14" runat="server" class="input input-sm form-control" Font-Size="Larger" MaxLength="13" onblur="assign(this.id,HFphno)" placeholder="Enter your contact details here" TextMode="Phone" ValidationGroup="SignUp" ValidateRequestMode="Enabled"></asp:TextBox>
                &nbsp;
              </div>
              <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator9" runat="server" ControlToValidate="TextBox14" ErrorMessage="*Enter your contact number" ForeColor="Red" ValidationGroup="SignUp" Display="Dynamic"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
              <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="TextBox14" ErrorMessage="*Enter number with (0 or +)&amp;(91/22)&amp; then the number" ForeColor="Red" SetFocusOnError="True" ValidateRequestMode="Enabled"
                ValidationExpression="(((^[\+,0][9][1])(((\s[0-9]{7,10})|(\S[0-9]{7,10}))|([-]\S[0-9]{7,10})))|((^[\+,0][2]{2,2})((\S[0-9]{7,8})|((([-])[0-9]{7,8})|(\s[0-9]{7,8})))))|(((^[6,7,8,9][0-9]{9,9}))|(^[0,\+](([9][1)|[6,7,8,9]))[0-9]{8,9}))" ValidationGroup="SignUp"
                Display="Dynamic" EnableViewState="False"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
              <br />
              <br />
              <div style="background-color: #D9853B">
                <asp:Label ID="Label16" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" Font-Italic="True" Font-Size="Larger" Text="User Type  ---&gt;"></asp:Label>
                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton1" runat="server" Font-Size="Larger" GroupName="UserType" Text="Engineer" ValidationGroup="SignUp" />
                <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton2" runat="server" Font-Size="Larger" GroupName="UserType" Text="Company" ValidationGroup="SignUp" /> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
              </div>
              <br />
              <br />
              <div style="background-color: #D9853B">
                <asp:Button ID="SUSbmtBtn" runat="server" Font-Size="Larger" Height="49px" Text="Register" Width="125px" ValidationGroup="SignUp" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" />
              </div>
              <br />
              <br />
              <div style="background-color: #FFF056">
                <asp:Button ID="Button4" runat="server" Height="53px" OnClick="Button4_Click" Text="Login Here" Width="123px" ValidationGroup="ChangeView" class="btn btn-warning btn-lg" />
              </div>
            </div>
          </asp:View>
        </asp:MultiView>

      </div>
    </form>
    <%--    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>--%>
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

      <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/MyJS.js"></script>
  </body>

  </html>
```

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace Abhiyantrix
{
    public partial class Login_Signup : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MultiView1.ActiveViewIndex = 0;
            Button1.Enabled = false;
            SUSbmtBtn.Enabled = false;
        }


        protected void Button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MultiView1.ActiveViewIndex = 1;
        }

        protected void Button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MultiView1.ActiveViewIndex = 0;
            //MultiView1.SetActiveView(Login);
        }

        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {

                SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
                con.ConnectionString = @"Data Source = OMKAR-PC ; Initial Catalog=ABHIYANTRIX PROJECT;Integrated Security = true;";
                con.Open();
                string query = "select * from Login where UserEmail = @Username and Password = @Password";
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Username", TextBox7.Text));
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Password", TextBox8.Text));
                SqlDataReader DR = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                if (DR.Read())
                {
                    Session["username"] = DR["UserName"];
                    string cmpUsern = DR["UserType"].ToString();
                   /* if (cmpUsern.ToString() == (string)"Client")
                    {
                        Response.Redirect("ClientPage.aspx");
                    }
                    else if ((string)cmpUsern == "Engineer")
                    {
                        Response.RedirectPermanent("WebForm1.aspx");
                    }*/

                    if (cmpUsern.ToString() == (string)"Client")
                    {
                        Response.Redirect("ClientPage.aspx");
                    }
                    else if ((string)cmpUsern == "Engineer")
                    {
                        Response.Redirect("WebForm1.aspx");
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Label4.Text = "Error";
                }
                con.Close();

            }
            catch (Exception E)
            {
                Label4.Text+= E.Message + "   E.InnerException:  " + E.InnerException;
                //throw;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Please help me I have added everything I think is needed if you still need something please ask for.
Note: Below is an ScreenShot of my signup view
[All the second block written in red are my regex](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e0QGs.jpg)

---

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem and this is how I solve it.

Your RegularExpressionValidator have `runat="server"` and `EnableClientScript="False"` which means it won't run at client side but at server side (from the code).

You need to add `Page.IsValid` inside your code, specifically where you are going to redirect, to prevent moving forward and show the `ErrorMessage` you set on the RegularExpressionValidator .

More info on why the Page.isValid would work [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.page.isvalid?view=netframework-4.8).